# Grid showing same data in two different column in outsystems

Tags: outsystems, lowcode

The app is about Worm Farming Manager. It has 3 tables as shown below

[image]

here I'm facing a problem in the transaction table. I scaffolded the screen using the Transaction table. Whenever I tried to add an entry in this transaction screen, the grid shows same container for both From and To columns but in TransactionDetails page, it's showing correctly.

For eg. I'm moving 10 pupae from container B to container C, as shown in the below image

[image]

The grid shows Container B in both places

[image]

How to fix this?

**Update #1**

This is the GetTransactions method

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the expression in the second column. It must be pointing to the same value as the first. As you have **two** foreign keys to the same table `{Transaction}.[FromContainerId]` and `{Transaction}.[ToContainerId]`. To solve this, you need to add another inner join between `{Transaction}` and  `{Container}` to get the `{Container}.[Name]` for the 'To Container' and map the new join result in the expression within the 'To Container' grid column.